Problem about binary/decimal bitwise and operation
I found a (maybe) fun problem, but I could not solve this.
$10110_{(10)} \& 10011_{(10)} = 10010_{(10)}$
$10110_{(2)} \& 10011_{(2)} = 10010_{(2)}$
$\&$ is the bitwise and operator.
Their string form was same. Like that example, I want to find (a, b) pairs that satisfy below:
$\text{string}(a_{(10)} \& b_{(10)}) = \text{string}(a_{(2)} \& b_{(2)})$
I don't think this is correct expression though, but anyway, like an example at the top, I want to find that pairs.
Can I find these (a, b) pairs more efficiently than bruteforcing all pairs?

An observation, for this example of $10110 \mathbin{&} 10011$, the one-bits of the ones in the decimal expressions are disjoint:
$$\begin{align*}
10000_{10} &= & 10\ 0111\ 0001\ 0000_2\
100_{10} &= & 110\ 0100_2\
10_{10} &= & 1010_2\
1_{10} &= & 1_2
\end{align*}$$
so there's no unwanted carry.

That's cool, then I should think how to find that disjoint numbers fast. thx!

Though having disjoint one-bits is not a necessary condition of being such $(a,b)$ pair. For example, the trivial $1100\mathbin &1100 = 1100$ or the barely less trivial $1101\mathbin &1100 = 1100$, even though $1000_{10}$ and $100_{10}$ share some bits.
